# _ViewImports.cshtml not working correctly on production

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I need help or some kind of  suggestion how to fix my _ViewImports file on production.

My _ViewImports contains only this lines:

```
@using Affiliate
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization
@inject IHtmlLocalizer<Affiliate.Localization.I18n> Localizer
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

On my dev machine (Visual Studio, Windows 10, IIS Express) the application loads the templates correctly.

On my production server (Ubuntu, nginx  + Kestrel running the dll). I get the template error that @Localizer is not recognized. 
If i move the inject command inside  every template it works as  it should.
Are there some restrictions what can you use in the _ViewImports file or do I miss something in my deploy configuration.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

OK, self answer is pretty simple.
The _ViewImports.cshtml file should be placed in some parent directory (subdirectory of views).
Since my templates are in a shared project, I needed to copy the file there and add it as embeded resource

Answer (score 0):

If you are having the same problem and tried copying the `_ViewImports.cshtml` and that still did not work for you, Make sure you are pointing to a valid `_Loayout.cshtml` for the links (stylesheets) are needed for this to work.